# What is method inlining?

Tags: java, function, methods

I've been trying to understand what that really means :

> **inline function**
>
> In C++, a member function defined in
>   the class declaration. (2) A function
>   call that the compiler replaces with
>   the actual code for the function. The
>   keyword inline  can be used to hint to
>   the compiler to perform inline
>   expansion of the body of a member or
>   nonmember function.
>
> **inline**
>
> To replace a function call with a copy
>   of the function's code during
>   compilation.

For example it is written something like :

> When a method is final, it may be
>   inlined.

Here : http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/final_methods.shtml

Can you give me an example or something or basically help me to understand what "it may be inlined" means.

Thanks.

Comment: This will be of help: http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/perf2.html#vm

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Inlining is an optimization performed by the Java Just-In-Time compiler.

If you have a method:

```
public int addPlusOne(int a, int b) {
  return a + b + 1;
}
```

which you call like this:

```
public void testAddPlusOne() {
  int v1 = addPlusOne(2, 5);
  int v2 = addPlusOne(7, 13);

  // do something with v1, v2
}
```

the compiler may decide to replace your function call with the body of the function, so the result would effectively look like this:

```
public void testAddPlusOne() {
  int v1 = 2 + 5 + 1;
  int v2 = 7 + 13 + 1

  // do something with v1, v2
}
```

The compiler does this to save the overhead of actually making a function call, which would involve pushing each parameter on to the stack.

This can clearly only be done for non-virtual functions.  Consider what would happen if the method was overriden in a sub class and the type of the object containing the method isn't known until runtime...how would the compiler know what code to copy: the base class's method body or the sub class's method body?  Since all methods are virtual by default in Java, you can explicitly mark those which cannot be overriden as `final` (or put them into a `final` class).  This will help the compiler figure out that method will never be overriden, and it is safe to inline.  (Note that the compiler can sometimes make this determination for non-final methods as well.)

Also, note the word **may** in the quote.  Final methods aren't guaranteed to be inlineable.  There are various ways you can guarantee a method isn't capable of being inlined, but no way to *force* the compiler to inline.  It will almost always know better than you anyway when inlining will help vs. hurt the speed of the resulting code.

See [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_expansion) for a good overview of benefits and problems.

Comment: Good answer, but as a note: If you have a non-final method that you *don't* override, a good JIT can figure that out and inline it anyway. If you then load a class that does override it, it can undo the inlining.

Comment: Good point, I added it to the answer body.

Comment: It is very explanatory, thanks for this great answer.

Comment: is byte code inlined, or source code? or one should say, only when compilation to byte code happens, then JVM decides whether to do some inlining?

Answer (score 14):

Let's say you have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Demo {
    public void method() {
        // call printMessage
        printMessage();
    }

    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

The call to `printMessage` could be "inlined" in the following way:

```
public class Demo {
    public void method() {
        // call printMessage
        System.out.println("Hello World"); // <-- inlined
    }

    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

(This is actually not done on the level of Java (not even on bytecode level) but during JIT-compilation, but the example above illustrates the concept of inlining.)

Now consider what would happen if the `printMessage` method was **overloaded by another class**, like this:

```
class SubDemo extends Demo {
    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println("Something else");
    }
}
```

Now if the compiler inlined the call to `Demo.printMessage` it would be stuck with `System.out.println("Hello World");` which would be **wrong** in case the object was actually an instance of `SubDemo`.

However, if the method was declared `final` this would not under any circumstances be the case. If the method is "final" it means that it can never be overridden with a new definition, thus, it is safe to inline it!

Comment: Also good answer, but as a note copied from another answer: If you have a non-final method that you don't override, a good JIT can figure that out and inline it anyway. If you then load a class that does override it, it can undo the inlining.

Comment: It is very explanatory, thanks for this great answer.

Answer (score 13):

Calling a function is not free.  The machine must maintain a stack frame so that it can return to the calling section of code when the called function is complete.  Maintaining the stack (including passing function parameters on this stack) takes time.

When a function is in-lined, the compiler replaces the call to the function with the function's code so that one can avoid the performance penalty of a function call at run-time.  This is one of the classic trade-offs in programming: the run-time code gets a little bigger (takes up more memory), but it runs a little faster.

Comment: Thanks. At the first paragraph, you are really right.