# what's Inlining in Java? Is there any relation between final keyword and Inlining?

Tags: java

Is it an example of inlining?

```
final class Executive extends Manager
{  
    public raiseSalary(int byPercent)
    {  
        return salary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you suspect there might be a relation?

Comment: i may be mistaken, but i think i read someplace that `final` methods could be inlined as a compiler optimization. Declaring a class final however has no relation to inlining as far as i can tell

Comment: @omu_negru that would be correct. I still suspect a nefarious origin of this question (read: exam)

Comment: @BoristheSpider not if your fields are public and non-final. Then the compiler cannot assume anything about them. Bonus points if they're volatile.

Comment: It's given in my book(core java by Cay S. Hostmann) but I can't understand what the Author is trying to say.

Comment: The second reason for final methods is efficiency. In earlier implementations of Java, if you
made a method final, you allowed the compiler to turn any calls to that method into inline
calls. Quoted from Thinking in Java

Comment: @omu_negru can you point to an online version of that from an answer, or perhaps find another source?

Comment: http://www.saeedsh.com/resources/Thinking%20in%20Java%204th%20Ed.pdf... Look for the chapter describing the `final` keyword. As a disclaimer, i do not own that site, it was the first that popped into google when searching for the reference

Comment: `inline` in programming means the same things as in English. It means to place code or data from one place into another place where it is used, usually for efficiency purposes.

Comment: BTW The compiler does almost no optimisations.  The main the `javac` does is constant evaluation which is a form of inlining of constant values.  It doesn't do much else.

Comment: does inlining moves the code to cache memory?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it an example of inlining?

No, it's not.

> Is there any relation between final keyword and Inlining?

Kind of. Read this:

> Contrary to the implication of many tips, methods declared as final
>   cannot be safely inlined by the compiler, because the method could
>   have a non-final declaration at runtime.
>
> To see why, suppose the compiler looks at class A and subclass B, and
>   sub-subclass C and sees a final method in A which it inlines into C.
>   But then at runtime the versions loaded for A and B are different and
>   the method is not final in A, and overridden in B. Then C uses the
>   incorrectly inlined version.

From http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/tips/final.shtml

Comment: However, the Hotspot JVM can make a lot of these calls at runtime.

Comment: @Thilo but so it can without the `final` keyword.

Comment: That's right. Even non-final methods can be inlined (if the JVM determines they are not being overridden).

Comment: @Andres-Would you mind describing your `second para`! I couldn't understand---`But then at runtime the versions loaded for A and B are different and the method is not final in A, and overridden in B`??? If initially the method has been declared final in A!!!Please don't mind,I am still a learner. THANKS.

Comment: The point is that the code at runtime may not be the same that as compile time. Therefore, inlining cannot be done safely.

Answer (score 1):

No, that it's not 'Inlining'.
Inlining is when the compiler decide to replace your function call with the body of the function.
Read here for full example https://stackoverflow.com/a/3925068/3743987

Answer (score 0):

Java compiler does not inline final classes or methods. You can check [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp1029/index.html) article.

As I know, inlining is applied to primitive constant statements. For example, the Java compiler replaces all the occurrences of `MY_NUMBER` constant below with 10 during the compilation phase. Therefor, at runtime, Java does not need to make memory access to read the value of `MY_NUMBER`.

```
private static final int MY_NUMBER = 10;
```