# Can declaring functions used in a Runnable outside the Runnable class yield greater performance?

Tags: java, performance

I have a piece of code that needs to be run on a separate thread to improve performance.
An example of where all the methods to be used by the Runnable are outside the Runnable class:

```
public class MyClass{
    public void myMethod() {
        new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
               task1();
               task2();
               task3();
            }
        }
    }

    public void task1(){

    }

    public void task2(){

    }

    public void task3(){

    }
}
```

An example of where all the methods to be used by the Runnable are inside the Runnable class:

```
public class MyClass{
    public void myMethod() {
        new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
               task1();
               task2();
               task3();
            }

            public void task1(){

            }

            public void task2(){

            }

            public void task3(){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm in a situation where any tiny bit of improvement in performance will make a significant improvement.

Comment: No, java will copy the code of the `tasks` in the part of code where you call them

Comment: Don't guess, use benchmarks. Look at Java JMH.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti Rubbish. Java doesn't copy code anywhere, let alone as you assert.

Comment: @MutaiMwiti You are seriously unlkely to get any benefit from micro-optimizations like this. You need to concern yourself with what happens *inside* these methods.

Comment: Theoretically, there should not be much difference. But, just try it practically and benchmark it.

Comment: @EJP look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3925068/6439023). Java compiler CAN replace function calls.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti You're doubly wrong. The Java compiler doesn't do anything. The JIT *can* **inline** methods, but that's not what you were describing.

Comment: [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) Just In Time Compilation. Who does this? Maybe the compiler?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti The Java compiler is `javac`. The `JIT` is a different compiler. There's a significant difference between them.

Comment: @LucaNicoletti 'Java compiler *can* replace function calls' is not the same thing as 'Java *will* copy the code'. If you're talking about inlining by the HotSpot JVM, it would help if you used the same terminology as everybody else.

Comment: @EJP my bad, wrong terminology. But that was what I meant, btw, we're OT.